# onFailure not getting called - onFailure(...) was not overriden, but callback was receiced

Tags: android, android-async-http

I am using android-async-http library from Loopj, onFailure not getting called in my code, I have tried all three methods..

W/JsonHttpRH﹕ onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received

```
private void get() {
    //Request parameters
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("key", API_KEY);

   MyRESTClient.get("/posts/", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            //some code
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
            mLoaderProgress.setText((long) 100 * bytesWritten / totalSize + "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            Log.d("Error----> ", ""+statusCode+" ------ "+ errorResponse);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is correct method to override,

```
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
    Log.d("Failed: ", ""+statusCode);
    Log.d("Error : ", "" + throwable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override correct method . Some of the onFailure are :
1.public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse)
2.public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse)
3.public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable)

Choose the proper onFailure to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Header

`import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;`